Page Unresponsive while changing filters
I have a page that loads dynamic charts from a API (Each chart is a equipment A01,A02,etc...), this charts are uptime/downtime charts with 300+ records.
When i change the filter to yearly that is where it comes more records from the api, the page gets  Unresponsive.
Its there any way to fix this issue, and still showing all the charts ?
The Page
The Code that im using for this page:
import { Grid } from "@material-ui/core";
import { createStyles, makeStyles, Theme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import moment from "moment";
import Chart from "react-apexcharts";
import { HomeReportEquipStatus } from "../../../../common/components/Icons/MesIcons";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import { t } from "i18next";

import React,{memo} from "react";

const EquipmentChart = ({ equipment,timeDuration,currentFilter,currentSelection,currentOperation,isPrinting }: any) => {

 
  const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
    createStyles({
      percentValue: {
        paddingRight: 30,
        fontWeight: 600,
        fontSize: 15,
        verticalAlign: "top",
      },
      plannedUnplannedValue: {
        paddingRight: 15,
        fontSize: 14,
        verticalAlign: "top",
      },
      statusRectangle: {
        width: 25,
        height: 25,
        background: "#F70505",
        borderRadius: "7px",
        marginRight: 5,
      },
      percentRectangle: {
        width: 20,
        height: 20,
        background: "#F70505",
        borderRadius: "7px",
        marginRight: 5,
      },
    })
  );
  const classes = useStyles();
  const history = useHistory();

  const weekDayArr = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"];
  const shift1 = ["6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14"];
  const shift2 = ["14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22"];
  const shift3 = ["22", "23", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"];
  const yearMonthArr = ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"];
  const currentYear = moment().year()

  const getTimeString = (selectionTypeOfFilter: string, val: string) => {
    let timePoint = {} as any,
      timeString = "";

    if (selectionTypeOfFilter === "yearly") {
      let tmpDays = Math.floor(Number(val));
      let tmpHours = Math.floor((Number(val) - tmpDays) * 30);
      timeString =
        (tmpDays > 0 ? tmpDays + " " + t('Dashboard.Months') + " " : "") +
        (tmpHours > 0 ? tmpHours + " " + t('Dashboard.Days') + " " : "");
    } else if (
      selectionTypeOfFilter === "monthly" ||
      selectionTypeOfFilter === "weekly"
    ) {
      let tmpDays = Math.floor(Number(val));
      let tmpHours = Math.floor((Number(val) - tmpDays) * 24);
      let tmpMinutes = Math.floor((((Number(val) - tmpDays) * 24) - tmpHours) * 60)
      timeString =
        (tmpDays > 0 ? tmpDays+ " " + t('Dashboard.Days') + " " : "") +
        (tmpHours > 0 ? tmpHours + " " + t('Dashboard.Hours') + " " : "") +
        (tmpMinutes > 0 ? tmpMinutes + " " + t('Dashboard.Minutes') : "");
    } else if (selectionTypeOfFilter === "daily") {
      timePoint = moment().startOf("day").add(moment.duration(val, "hours"));
      timeString = timePoint.hours() + + " " + t('Dashboard.Hours') + " "  + timePoint.minutes() + " " + t('Dashboard.Minutes');
    }
    return timeString;
  };

  function getDaysOfTheMonth(){
     const month = currentSelection ;
     const firstDayOfMonth = moment([currentYear, month]);
     const numDaysInMonth = firstDayOfMonth.daysInMonth();

     const daysArray = [];

     for (let day = 1; day <= numDaysInMonth; day++) {
         daysArray.push(day);
     }
 
     return daysArray;
  }
  

  function handleXAxis(value: any) {

    if (currentFilter === "yearly") {
      return yearMonthArr[Number(value)];
    } else if (currentFilter === "monthly") {
      let daysInMonth = getDaysOfTheMonth()
      return daysInMonth[Number(value)]
    }else if(currentFilter === 'weekly'){
      return weekDayArr[Number(value)] || " "; 
    } else if (currentFilter === "shift") {
      if(currentSelection === 1) {
        return shift1[Number(value)];
      }else if(currentSelection === 2) {
        return shift2[Number(value)];
      }else if(currentSelection === 3) {
        return shift3[Number(value)];
      } 
    }else{
      if(timeDuration.duration > 28){
        return value + 1 
      }else{
        return value
      }
    }
  }

  let EquipTimeLineChartOptions: any = (equipData: any, timeDuration: any) => ({
    chart: {
      id: currentFilter === "shift" ? `basic-bar${Math.random()}` : undefined,      
      // height: 300,
      stacked: true,
      toolbar: {
        show: false,
      },
    },
    plotOptions: {
      bar: {
        barHeight: '100%',
        horizontal: true,
        dataLabels: {
          position: "bottom",
        },
      },
    },
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: true,
      textAnchor: "start",
      style: {
        colors: ["#fff"],
        fontWeight: 200,
      },
      formatter: (val: string, opt: any) => {
        let tmpStatus = opt.w.globals.seriesNames[opt.seriesIndex];
        if (tmpStatus === "undefined") return getTimeString(currentFilter, val);
        else if (tmpStatus.startsWith("Production"))
          return (
            tmpStatus.substr("Production".length , 8) +
            " " +
            tmpStatus.substr("Production".length + 8) +
            "KPC"
          );
        else return tmpStatus + " " + getTimeString(currentFilter, val);
      },
      position: "bottom",
    },
    tooltip: {
      enabled: true,
      followCursor: true,
      custom: ({ series, seriesIndex, dataPointIndex, w }: any) => {
        let tmpStatus = w.globals.seriesNames[seriesIndex];

        let title = w.globals.tooltip.tooltipTitle.outerText;
        let mouseYPosition = w.globals.tooltip.tooltipPosition?.ttCtx?.clientY;
        let content = "";

        if (tmpStatus.startsWith("Production"))
          content =
            '<div class="report_tooltip mt-3">' +
            '<div class="report_tooltip_left">' +
            "Order:" +
            "</div>" +
            '<div class="report_tooltip_right">' +
            tmpStatus.substr("Production".length, 8) +
            "</div>" +
            "</div>" +
            '<div class="report_tooltip">' +
            '<div class="report_tooltip_left">' +
            "Quantity:" +
            "</div>" +
            '<div class="report_tooltip_right">' +
            tmpStatus.substr("Production".length + 8) +
            " KPC" +
            "</div>" +
            "</div>" +
            '<div class="report_tooltip mb-5">' +
            '<div class="report_tooltip_left">' +
            "Duration:" +
            "</div>" +
            '<div class="report_tooltip_right">' +
            getTimeString(
              currentFilter,
              series[seriesIndex][dataPointIndex]
            ) +
            "</div>" +
            "</div>";
        else
          content =
            '<div class="report_tooltip mt-3">' +
            '<div class="report_tooltip_left">' +
            "Status:" +
            "</div>" +
            '<div class="report_tooltip_right">' +
            tmpStatus +
            "</div>" +
            "</div>" +
            '<div class="report_tooltip mb-5">' +
            '<div class="report_tooltip_left">' +
            "Duration:" +
            "</div>" +
            '<div class="report_tooltip_right">' +
            getTimeString(
              currentFilter,
              series[seriesIndex][dataPointIndex]
            ) +
            "</div>" +
            "</div>";

        return (
          '<div class="apexcharts-tooltip-title" style="margin-top: ' +
          mouseYPosition +
          'px">' +
          title +
          "</div>" +
          '<div class="apexcharts-tooltip-content">' +
          content +
          "</div>"
        );
      },
    },
    stroke: {
      width: 2,
      colors: ["#fafafa"],
    },
    xaxis: {
      show: false,
      hideOverflowingLabels: false,
      categories: [equipment.equipementID || ""],
      //error in apexchart package, need to set the tickamount of yAxis in xAxis of HORIZONTAL table
      tickAmount: timeDuration.duration,
      min: 0,
      max: timeDuration.duration,
      scrollbar: {
        enabled: true
      },
      labels: {
        rotate: -45,
        minHeight: 20,
        maxHeight: 100,
        formatter: function (value:any) {
          console.log(value)
          return handleXAxis(value);
        }
      },
    },
    yaxis: {
      show: true,
      showAlways: true,
      axisBorder: {
        show: false,
      },
      //error in apexchart package, need to style the XLabel in yAxis of HORIZONTAL table
      labels: {
        show: false,
      },
    },
    fill: {
      opacity: 1,
      type: "solid",
    },
    colors:
      equipData.timeLine?.length > 0
        ? equipData.timeLine.map((item: any) => item.statusColor)
        : ["red", "blue", "green"],
    legend: {
      show: false,
    },
    grid: {
      show: true,
      borderColor: "#90A4AE",
      strokeDashArray: 0,
      position: "back",
      xaxis: {
        lines: {
          show: false,
        },
      },
      yaxis: {
        lines: {
          show: false,
        },
      },
    },
  });


  function filterLastTimeLine(timeline:any){

    const filteredArray = timeline.filter((item:any) => item.endAt === null);
    return filteredArray
  }


  const TimeLineReport = () => {
    
      
      let unplannedDowntimePercent = 0 as any,
      plannedDowntimePercent = 0 as any,
      equipProd = 0,
      equipStandBy = 0,
      equipSetup = 0,
      equipDowntime = 0;


  

    return (
      <Grid item xs={12} style={{height:'100%'}} className="equipment-report-chart" >
        <HomeReportEquipStatus status={filterLastTimeLine(equipment.timeLine)} />
        <div
          style={{
            width: equipment.equipmentID?.length * 20,
            display: "inline-block",
            fontSize: 15,
            fontWeight: 500,
            verticalAlign: "top",
            padding: "39px 0 0 10px",
          }}
          className="pointer-cursor"
          onClick={() => {
            history.push({
              pathname:
                "/orders/" +
                equipment.id +
                "/" +
                currentOperation +
                "/all",
              state: {},
            });
          }}
        >
          {equipment.equipmentID}
        </div>

        <div
          style={{
            width:
              "calc(100% - " +
              (equipment.equipmentID?.length * 20 + 30) +
              "px)",
            display: "inline-block",
            verticalAlign: "top",
            height:"100%"
          }}
        >
         
          <Chart options={EquipTimeLineChartOptions(equipment,timeDuration) as any} height={currentFilter === 'yearly' ? 80 : 90 } width="100%" series={
              equipment.timeLine?.length > 0
                ? equipment.timeLine.map((item: any) => {
                    
                    equipDowntime = equipment.downtimePercent ? equipment.downtimePercent: 0;
                    unplannedDowntimePercent = equipment.unPlannedDowntimePercent ? equipment.unPlannedDowntimePercent : 0;
                    plannedDowntimePercent = equipment.plannedDowntimePercent ? equipment.plannedDowntimePercent : 0;
                    equipProd = equipment.productionPercent ? equipment.productionPercent : 0;
                    equipStandBy = equipment.standByPercent ?  equipment.standByPercent : 0;
                    equipSetup = equipment.setupPercent ? equipment.setupPercent : 0 ;
                    return {
                      name:
                        item.status +
                        (item.status === "Production"
                          ? item.orderID +""+item.orderProdQty
                          : ""),
                      data: [item.mappedDuration],
                    };
                  })
                : []
            }
            type="bar"
          />
          
          <Grid
            container
            style={{ width: "100%", paddingLeft: 80 }}
          >
            <div className={classes.percentRectangle} />
            
            <div style={{ display: "inherit" }}>
              <div className={classes.percentValue}>
                {equipDowntime  + "%"}
              </div>
            </div>
            {equipDowntime !== 0 &&
            <div className={classes.plannedUnplannedValue}>
                {t("home.Unplanned")}
            </div>
            }
            {equipDowntime !== 0 &&
            <div className={classes.percentValue}>
                {unplannedDowntimePercent + "%"}
            </div>
            }
            {equipDowntime !== 0 &&
            <div className={classes.plannedUnplannedValue}>
                {t("home.Planned")}
            </div>
            }
            {equipDowntime !== 0 &&
            <div className={classes.percentValue}>
                {plannedDowntimePercent + "%"}
            </div>
            }
            <div
              className={classes.percentRectangle}
              style={{ background: "#14CC3C" }}
            />
            <div className={classes.percentValue}>
              {equipProd + "%"}
             
            </div>
            <div
              className={classes.percentRectangle}
              style={{ background: "#F6E652" }}
            />
            <div className={classes.percentValue}>
              {equipStandBy + "%"}
            </div>
            <div
              className={classes.percentRectangle}
              style={{ background: "#274AFF" }}
            />
            <div className={classes.percentValue}>
              {equipSetup + "%"}
            </div>
          </Grid>
        </div>
      </Grid>
    );
  };

  return (
    <Grid container style={{ marginTop: "15px" }}>
      {TimeLineReport()}
    </Grid>
  );
};

export default memo(EquipmentChart);

There is also a parent component that is passing the props to the Equipment component above:
 {equipmentData
              // .slice(0, itemsToShow)
              .map((equipment: any, index: number) => (
                <div style={{ height: "110px" }}>
                  <EquipmentChart
                    // key={index}
                    equipment={equipment}
                    timeDuration={timeDuration}
                    currentFilter={filters.selectionType}
                    currentSelection={filters.selection}
                    currentOperation={filters.operation}
                    isPrinting={isPrinting}
                  />
                </div> 
               ))}  

Thank you in advance :)
My end result is to have the page working at normal rate on filter change.

You are using the array methods like .map in multiple places. You also have a formatter that uses getTimeString. The formatter and the .map callbacks are invoked one time for each item in the timeline. If your timeline has 1000 items, the .map callback and the formatter function will be invoked 1000 times each. While all this computation is taking place the UI thread will be blocked.
You are going to have to refactor this to prevent the UI threat from being blocked. There is a lot of logic going on inside the chart library like for example what you are doing in handleXAxis. I recommend you try the following:

Your goal should be that the chart library only does one thing: rendering. Filtering and formatting should take place in a parent component. You prepare the data for the charting library and then just pass it ready to be rendered.

MAP You should try to split your timeline data and use webworkers to filter and format in the background. For example, you could:

2.1 Split your data into, for example, 4 chunks. Avoid map, filter`` and reduce.
2.2 Pass each chunk to a web worker.
2.3 Compute the formatting and filtering for each available filter and return the result.


REDUCE When the webworkers are done use a Map<filter, dataReady> to merge all the results.

CACHE Cache your data, so when a filter changes there is no need to do all the formatting and filtering computation again.


These patterns are known as map/reduce, and they are how systems with large datasets like Hadoop work.
I'm sorry I don't have time to get this done, but here is an AI-generated code sample that should provide you with more guidance:
// Interface Definitions
interface TimelineItem {
  status: string;
  orderID?: string | number;
  orderProdQty?: string | number;
  mappedDuration: number;
  endAt?: Date;
}

interface Equipment {
  equipmentID: string;
  id: string;
  timeLine: TimelineItem[];
  downtimePercent?: number;
  unPlannedDowntimePercent?: number;
  plannedDowntimePercent?: number;
  productionPercent?: number;
  standByPercent?: number;
  setupPercent?: number;
}

// Split the equipment array into chunks
function splitIntoChunks<T>(array: T[], chunkSize: number): T[][] {
  const results: T[][] = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i += chunkSize) {
    results.push(array.slice(i, i + chunkSize));
  }
  return results;
}

// Initialize the equipment data (replace with actual data)
declare const equipment: Equipment[];

// Split the equipment data into 4 chunks
const chunks = splitIntoChunks(equipment, Math.ceil(equipment.length / 4));

// Function to create a web worker
function createWorker(workerCode: string): Worker {
  const blob = new Blob([workerCode], { type: "application/javascript" });
  const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  return new Worker(url);
}

// Web worker code
const workerCode = `
  onmessage = function(e) {
    const { chunk } = e.data;
    const yearly = new Map();
    const monthly = new Map();
    const daily = new Map();
    
    function addToMap(map, key, item) {
      if (!map.has(key)) {
        map.set(key, []);
      }
      map.get(key).push(item);
    }
    
    chunk.forEach(equipment => {
      equipment.timeLine.forEach(item => {
        if (item.endAt) {
          const endAt = new Date(item.endAt);
          addToMap(yearly, endAt.getFullYear(), item);
          addToMap(monthly, \`\${endAt.getFullYear()}-\${endAt.getMonth() + 1}\`, item);
          addToMap(daily, \`\${endAt.getFullYear()}-\${endAt.getMonth() + 1}-\${endAt.getDate()}\`, item);
        }
      });
    });
    
    postMessage({ yearly: Array.from(yearly), monthly: Array.from(monthly), daily: Array.from(daily) });
  }
`;

// Create web workers
const workers = chunks.map(chunk => {
  const worker = createWorker(workerCode);
  worker.postMessage({ chunk });
  return worker;
});

// Collect results from all workers
const results: { yearly: [string, TimelineItem[]][], monthly: [string, TimelineItem[]][], daily: [string, TimelineItem[]][] }[] = [];

workers.forEach(worker => {
  worker.onmessage = function(e) {
    results.push(e.data);
    worker.terminate();
    if (results.length === workers.length) {
      aggregateResults(results);
    }
  };
});

// Function to aggregate results
function aggregateResults(results) {
  const finalMap = {
    yearly: new Map<string, TimelineItem[]>(),
    monthly: new Map<string, TimelineItem[]>(),
    daily: new Map<string, TimelineItem[]>()
  };
  
  results.forEach(result => {
    result.yearly.forEach(([key, items]) => {
      if (!finalMap.yearly.has(key)) {
        finalMap.yearly.set(key, []);
      }
      finalMap.yearly.get(key).push(...items);
    });
    
    result.monthly.forEach(([key, items]) => {
      if (!finalMap.monthly.has(key)) {
        finalMap.monthly.set(key, []);
      }
      finalMap.monthly.get(key).push(...items);
    });
    
    result.daily.forEach(([key, items]) => {
      if (!finalMap.daily.has(key)) {
        finalMap.daily.set(key, []);
      }
      finalMap.daily.get(key).push(...items);
    });
  });

  console.log("Final Aggregated Result: ", finalMap);
  // Do something with the finalMap
}


sorry i did not understand can you provide a more related example please ?
